# Php: modify attribute html tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have these html tags:

```
 <select name="ct" id="ct">
        <option value="-1">Tutte</option>
        <option value="1">Da verificare</option>
        <option value="2">Verificate</option>
        <option value="3">Approvate</option>
        <option value="4">Respinte</option>
        <option value="5">Pubblicate</option>
        <option value="6">Scadute</option>
        <option value="7">Proposte</option>
        <option value="8">Rifiutate</option>
        <option value="9">Ritirate</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="7,8,1">Proposte / Rifiutate / Da verificare</option>
   </select>
```

I want to change the attribute value **of the selected option** (which contains "7,8,1") to value="-1", so it will look like:

```
<option selected="selected" value="-1">Proposte / Rifiutate / Da verificare</option>
```

I tried with:

```
$dom_richieste->getElementsByTagName('options')->getAttribute('value').value="-1";
```

But that's not working...

Comment: `$dom_richieste->getElementsByTagName('options')->getAttribute('value').value="-1";` makes no sense and is invalid in both Javascript and PHP. Show how you set `$dom_richieste`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are need something like:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('option') as $item) {
    if ($item->getAttribute('selected') == "selected")
        $item->setAttribute("value", "-1");
}
```

This way you pass on your option items and set the value of the selected ones

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$("#ct option[value='7,8,1']").val("-1");`

```js
$("#ct option[value='7,8,1']").val("-1");
console.log($("#ct").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ct" id="ct">
        <option value="-1">Tutte</option>
        <option value="1">Da verificare</option>
        <option value="2">Verificate</option>
        <option value="3">Approvate</option>
        <option value="4">Respinte</option>
        <option value="5">Pubblicate</option>
        <option value="6">Scadute</option>
        <option value="7">Proposte</option>
        <option value="8">Rifiutate</option>
        <option value="9">Ritirate</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="7,8,1">Proposte / Rifiutate / Da verificare</option>
   </select>
```

I suggest you to check how you created this drop down, and if possible replace there instead after creating drop down.

Comment: This is very specific to the question - make it more generic by searching the 'selected' attribute

Answer (score 0):

You have used `getElementsByTagName('options')` in your code and no tag available with name `options`. Instead you should use correct tag name `option`.